# Data Structure of Objects - Run Query for each

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application that I am refactoring. It runs a query for every object in a List structure. This takes a considerable amount of time. Is there a way to better utilize the need to run a sql for every object in the data structure?

Comment: Of course there is. You are probably talking about the **N + 1** query problem. You can retrieve them all using a single query, though it has it caveats. If you post the specific table structure and SQL select, we can help you with the specifics of the solution.